# Modify log format on runtime using Monolog and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, monolog

I need write a customlog on laravel 5.3, and modify on runtime for add some extra information.

So far I have managed to do it, but the code does not work because what I can do is add a new instance of the log, which duplicates the lines in each modification of the format.

My handicap is that I do not know how to return or if this is possible, the current handler of the logging system, and simply pass it the format modification.

The code below allows me to modify the format line, but only once.

If I run it again, start duplicating the lines, and what is not like, create the handler in another way, or use the existing one that would be appropriate.

```
$maxFiles = config('app.log_max_files');
$path     = storage_path('/logs/cprsync.log');

// Really I don't need this because this are on Laravel App, but with this method y can create a $handler for modify format 
$handler = new RotatingFileHandler($path, is_null($maxFiles) ? 5 : $maxFiles, config('app.log_level'));
(is_null(config('cprsync.activejob'))) ? $job = '' : $job=' ['.config('cprsync.activejob').']';
$logFormat = "[%datetime%] [%level_name%]".$job.": %message% %context% %extra%\n";

$formatter = new LineFormatter($logFormat,null,true,true);
$handler->setFormatter($formatter); // What I really want is to make this change ...

// Push handler
$log->getMonolog()->pushHandler($handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the prettiest (like in Symfony you can just put some YAML rules in the services.yml and you've changed your log format), but this seems to be a very valid option and basically builds on what you're doing already:

http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/monolog-for-custom-logging

TL;DR: Create a custom logging class with a function `write()` that basically contains the code OP has posted. Then add that class to your facades and you can log with `MyCustomLogger::write($message);`

EDIT: This isn't really what OP requested, since this doesn't change the format on runtime.

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question, but it leads me to another question and other answers. I am not asking for a path, to do an additional class of log, but for the possibility to modify only and exclusively the format of the log, already existing in the app. I also indicated that the modification already works for me. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I figured it out just a few seconds after you posted. In my opinion it's always better to declare an explicit class instead of doing some magic on a couple of log lines, because it's easier to find, extend and fix later. Still doesn't answer your question though ;)